# Unable to Load High Resolution Images

Tags: android, image, android-fragments, loading

Having an issue regarding the use of [highresolutionimages](/questions/tagged/highresolutionimages) in my [fragments](/questions/tagged/fragments).

I've got 2 sets of [fragments](/questions/tagged/fragments), the first having 4 [fragments](/questions/tagged/fragments) and the next set having 6 [fragments](/questions/tagged/fragments).Having a button in the first set of the [fragments](/questions/tagged/fragments) which when clicked redirects to the second set of [fragments](/questions/tagged/fragments).

Used the [BitmapFactoryOptions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8) to load the images.Works fine for the first set of [fragments](/questions/tagged/fragments), But not working with second set.The `ShuttingDownVM` Error occurs...

any help would be grateful..

thanks in advance :D

Comment: Need some more information - can you post the logcat and some relevant code? Are you calling System.exit() anywhere?

Comment: I think you're having the error,

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question but it may alleviate your problems as many other companies and tools have solved image problems in Android for you.

You may want to check out an image library like [ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) (which has deep zoom support for large images) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)